# TFS api build status and create release

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

Hey all I'm new to the TFS api world so help would be great!

I am looking to gather information on my projects from the tfs version 15.112.26307.0 (2017) server.

My TFS web URL that lists ALL my projects is : http://tfsserv001:8080/tfs/prog/_projects

My TFS test app is this: http://tfsserv001:8080/tfs/prog/---2017

I am looking to get the build status from the Build & Release > Builds tab via API:
[image]

And after its **succeeded** I would then like it to create a release:
[image]

Are both above possible by using the TFS api?

Comment: What is insufficient about the build in release triggers?

Comment: @daniel im just making it automated. thats my preference.

Comment: The triggers you can set on a release **are** automated. The release is created when the trigger conditions are satisfied, with no user intervention.

Comment: Hi StealthRT, any update on this? Have my solution help you figured out it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is related [**Rest API**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-a-build) to get build result- include the status info

```
 "result": "succeeded",
```

You could also use Rest API to [create(trigger) a release](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases) based on some info such as build ID.

For more details you could take a look at this blog shows how to use rest api in powershell:

---

Moreover, *Daniel* is right. You could  check the **Continuous deployment**(*create release and deploy whenever a build completes*) when you create  a new release definition or select in [triggers](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/triggers) of the release definition. TFS server will handle this automatically, without the need of user intervention.

[image]

---

***Update***

A example when you open a build result in the web portal just as:
[image]

In the entire url there will include a **buildID** such as `buildID=49`. So according to above screenshot, you should use

```
 Get http://xxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/ScrumMttApple/_apis/build/builds/49/?api-version=2.0
```

Then will get below JSON result:

```
  "id": 49,
  "buildNumber": "20170525.5",
  "status": "completed",
  "result": "succeeded",
  "queueTime": "2017-05-25T19:17:39.6545026Z",
  "startTime": "2017-05-25T19:17:42.2482602Z",
  "finishTime": "2017-05-25T19:25:15.6808731Z",
  "url": "http://win-kev0061habi:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/bdd4809b-e6dd-4cb8-8e60-762373b20cdc/_apis/build/Builds/49",
  "definition": {
    "path": "\\",
    "type": "build",
    "revision": 5,
    "id": 14,
    "name": "OrdertTest", 
.....
```

Comment: when i try using     **http://tfsserv001:8080/DefaultCollection** it comes up as this page does not exist?

Comment: @StealthRT It will only come up when you create your release definition first time. If you already have the release definition, you could edit it, click `...` in the right of the release definition and select **triggers**, check **Continuous Deployment** and select corresponding build definition.

Comment: i mean using the api calls. the examples show that but my url doesnt seem to have it.

Comment: @StealthRT It works well in my side. Did you follow the every Parameter in your api url `GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version={version}` make sure you also include the project(name or ID) in your api url.

Comment: If you noticed in my OP I have my URL path listed. I tried **http://tfsserv001:8080/DefaultCollection/tfs/prod/---2017/_apis/build/b‌​uilds/20170913.2?api-‌​version=2.0** But that does not seem to show anything but **Page not found**

Comment: @StealthRT `20170913.2` is a build number not a build ID, you should use the build ID instead, have update my answer above with a detail example, please kindly review it.